# Double slit experiment in reflection

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, reflection, laser, double-slit-experiment

Can the double slit experiment be recreated with two reflecting strips with reflected laser light.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any conceptual reason it would not work. Providing the screen on which one observes interferences is well behind the light source, so as to avoid contamination…

Comment: Or the screen is before the laser and can not see it. Thank you very much.